# CKEDIT getData: wait for method to finish before submitting data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ckeditor

I register each of my textareas by calling the `CKonBlur` one for each of them in a `$(document).ready(..` method:

```
function CKonBlur(name) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].on('blur', function () {
        CKsync(name);  // push HTML data from CKEDITOR into the associated textarea
        storeNotifications(name);  // submit the textarea to the server
    });
}


function CKsync(name) {
    $("textarea#" + name).val(CKEDITOR.instances[name].getData());
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that `getData` is asynchronous and I simply can't figure out a way of waiting for it to finish before (!) submitting the data.

**Question: how can I ensure that `getData` is finished before calling the `storeNotifications` method?**

I've also attempted to use the `checkDirty` without any success (it just crashed the browser):

```
function CKsync(name) {
    while (CKEDITOR.instances[name].checkDirty() == true);
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    $("textarea#" + name).val(CKEDITOR.instances[name].getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure that `getData()` is not asynchronous. `setData()` is, but `getData()` isn't. It couldn't be, because it returns a value. You've got a bug somewhere else.

Comment: I don't that it is a bug; once I changed storeNotifications and handed over the response of CKEDITOR.instances[name].getData() directly, it worked immediately correctly in all cases...